# Vim 7.4 hybrid number mode not working

Tags: line-numbers

I recently discovered that Vim 7.4 enables a hybrid number mode, such that if you do `set nu` and `set rnu`, you'll see the absolute line number of the current line and relative line numbers everywhere else (see [here](http://codeyarns.com/2015/03/24/absolute-relative-and-hybrid-line-numbers-in-vim/) and [here](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2013/vims-new-hybrid-line-number-mode/)). I set this up on a Linux machine and it works great. Unfortunately it's not working on my MacBook Pro (El Capitan). If I type `:set rnu` I'll get relative numbers with `0` at the cursor line, and if I then type `:set nu` it will switch to only absolute line numbers, unlike what I see on the Linux machine. I have Vim 7.4 installed via Homebrew. How do I get this to work? Do I need to reinstall with some particular setting?

**UPDATE 1**

The output of `vim --version` is

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr  5 2016 22:32:58)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-1707
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +terminfo
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +textobjects
+channel         -gettext         -mzscheme        +timers
+cindent         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clientserver    +iconv           +packages        -toolbar
+clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +job             +perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xsmp
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_save
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xpm
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -F/usr/local/Frameworks -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -Os -w -pipe -march=native -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: /usr/bin/clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -F/usr/local/Frameworks -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -o vim        -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework Cocoa   -fstack-protector  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -framework Python   -lruby.2.0.0 -lobjc
```

**UPDATE 2**

Vim 7.4 installed via Homebrew on my iMac desktop has hybrid number mode working fine, so there must be something specific about my laptop, but I have no idea what. Moving my `.vimrc` and packages somewhere else didn't change anything.

Comment: It might be a bug. Consider reporting at https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues

Comment: I thought Vim was different from MacVim. If I used `brew install vim` and not  `brew install macvim` would that still be the place to report it?

Comment: No, I assumed you were on MacVim. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the problem was not with Vim 7.4, Homebrew, Macs, or any combination of the 3. Just my brain. I was used to `vi` pointing to the `vim` that I want, but in my case `vim` points to the Homebrewed version and `vi` points to the version originally on my Mac, which was Vim 7.3. I usually use `vi` and `vim` interchangeably and that shot me in the foot here. I have `vi` aliased to the Homebrewed Vim now and everything is dandy.